# gwt beginner- getting error when I make an RPC call on server- same code works in gwt dev mode

Tags: gwt, rpc

I have created a simple gwt application (with gwt 2.4) that makes a single RPC call.

When I run this in GWT Dev mode, it runs fine, however when I try to run this on a server-
this is the message that I get --

```
POST http://app.sparkcrawler.com/com.arvindikchari.auth.App/AuthenticationService 404 (Not Found)
```

I have copied all files from the WAR folder in my Eclipse GWT project, to the web server's folder. The web server uses Tomcat 5.5(with Cpanel control panel). I copied these files, after successfully compiling the files ("GWT Compile Project")...

What have i done wrong here? Have i missed some files? I have copied everything from war folder, including "WEB-INF" folder and its contents, to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I think, copying the Eclipse project's WAR folder is not the appropriate way to deploy a GWT application to a server.

You first have to compile for production mode (see [Understanding the GWT compiler](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideJavaToJavaScriptCompiler)), then with the resulting JavaScript files, create a WAR including server side classes which you can deploy to a Tomcat server. (See [Deploy a GWT Application](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying))

You can use Ant or Maven to automate this process.

Comment: @vanje- sorry, thats my mistake that i forgot to mention this in the question- i compiled the project successfully and only after that copied the files into the server... Also, in cpanel based server, you can directly copy the files (jsp/servlet) into the server- I dont know how to upload a WAR directly to the server- and the server does have separate folder for "WEB-INF"...